# How to prove this product rule?

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

If $f,g:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable in $x_0\in\Omega$ ($\Omega$ is open), then the function $(f*g)$ is differentiable in $x_0$ and:

$(f\cdot g)'(x_0)=f'(x_0)g(x_0)+f(x_0)g'(x_0)$

How to prove this product rule?

(Note: specifically for $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: With $*$ you mean the composition or the convolution?

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco Seems to me, the author means the usual product of two real numbers.

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco How can it be composition when the domain of one isn't the codomain of the other? As for the question, do you know how to prove the product rule for functions $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: For this reason I ask you that, the composition is not possible.

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco I think it's the usual product.

Comment: It is reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ is a point held fixed, and $h\in{\mathbb R}^n$ is a variable vector, whereas $f$, $g$ and $p:=f\cdot g$ are scalar functions. Both $f$ and $g$ are bounded in some neighborhood of the point $x$.  Therefore we may write
$$\eqalign{p(x+h)-p(x)&=\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)g(x) + f(x)\bigl(g(x+h)-g(x)\bigr)\cr&\qquad\qquad+\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)\bigl(g(x+h)-g(x)\bigr)\cr
&=\bigl(df(x).h+o(|h|)\bigr)g(x)+f(x)\bigl(dg(x).h+o(|h|)\bigr)\cr&\qquad\qquad+
\bigl(df(x).h+o(|h|)\bigr)\bigl(dg(x).h+o(|h|)\bigr)\cr
&=g(x)\>df(x).h+f(x)\>dg(x).h+o(|h|)\ \cr}$$
when $h\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{d(f(x)g(x))}{dx}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)+f(x+h)g(x)-f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x))+g(x)(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h}
\end{align}
Then you can consider that $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)=f(x)$.

When $x\in \mathbb R^n$, you have $$\frac{dF}{dx} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}e_i$$ and the definition of the derivative is
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+he_i)-F(x)}{h}$$

Comment: Since $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you should write $\left\Vert h \right\Vert$ I guess

Comment: $h$ does not belong to $\mathbb{R}^n$ here. The author of the comment neglected the partial derivative $\partial$ signs from the series. $x + h e_1$ refers to a straight line parallel to $e_1$ here!

Comment: As others have said, the first line is a nonstarter. Better to go with $f(x+h) = f(x) + df(x)(h) = o(|h|),$ same with $g.$

Comment: That $=$ at the end should have been a $+.$